# Last record being omit from formula

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

I wrote some logic to determine if a kcode (doctor billing) is correct for a patient. I wrote some logic to loop through the records and place in column the ID of the correct CP (care provider) who deserves the kcode. For some reason the last record or last 2 records are not following the logic. This is my logic code (inside a cursor):

```
OPEN kcode_count;
kcode_loop: LOOP

    FETCH kcode_count INTO dbPTNT_ID, dbCP_ID, dbSEEN, holder, dbDATE, holder2;
    IF done THEN
        LEAVE kcode_loop;
    END IF;

    IF dbPTNT_ID <> setPTNT_ID THEN
        IF setPTNT_ID <> 0 THEN
            UPDATE tmp_kcodes
            SET SHOULD_GET = setCP_ID
            WHERE setPTNT_ID = PTNT_ID;
        END IF;
        SET setPTNT_ID = dbPTNT_ID;
        SET setCP_ID = dbCP_ID;
        SET setSEEN = dbSEEN;
        SET setDATE = dbDATE;

    ELSEIF dbSEEN > setSEEN THEN
            SET setCP_ID = dbCP_ID;
            SET setSEEN = dbSEEN;
            SET setDATE = dbDATE;

    ELSEIF dbSEEN = setSEEN THEN
        IF dbDATE < setDATE THEN
            SET setCP_ID = dbCP_ID;
            SET setSEEN = dbSEEN;
            SET setDATE = dbDATE;
        END IF;
    END IF;


END LOOP kcode_loop;
CLOSE kcode_count;
```

As seen below, in the SHOULD_GET column, the last two records produce NULL. Is there any reason why?

[image]

Comment: You have used `SET SHOULD_GET` only in a single block, it might not going into that block, please check as of your said logic.

Comment: @AvishekChat That is because i want it to only update after it has gone through each particular patient ID

Comment: you should put a `print` or `temp debug table` after the `UPDATE     tmp_kcodes
            SET SHOULD_GET = setCP_ID
            WHERE setPTNT_ID = PTNT_ID;`, to see when and by what exactly going to be updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you only update `SHOULD_GET` column **after** you processed a certain patient (patient 20092469's data is updated when the loop fetches the 1st 20092491 patient's record). For the last patient this obviously cannot happen, the `dbPTNT_ID <> setPTNT_ID` condition will never be satisfied.

At first glance I would repeat the

```
    IF setPTNT_ID <> 0 THEN
        UPDATE tmp_kcodes
        SET SHOULD_GET = setCP_ID
        WHERE setPTNT_ID = PTNT_ID;
    END IF;
```

block right after the end of the kcode_loop to update the last patient being processed.

Another solution could be to append a "dummy" row at the end of the resultset returned by the cursor using a union, this way the `dbPTNT_ID <> setPTNT_ID` condition will be triggered for the last patient as well.